# Unreal Engine 4.25 travel failure when calling game over

Tags: unreal-engine4

so I'm trying to create a mobile game in UE4.25, working in the blueprints section for this part, but I put game over into its own level because it was causing problems when in the same level as the main game. When trying to call game over after the player hits an enemy with less score than the enemy takes away, I call openlevel which goes to DEMO_GameOver (the level) but I get the "travel failure" error.
anyone know how to fix this? (see attached images for more information)[image: output the console gives]

[image: code for the enemy that I'm using to send the player to gameover]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: SOLVED

after looking back several times at this post to see if anyone had responded with a solution, I worked out the problem randomly while looking at the screen. I realised that I had named the level I was trying to open "DEMO_GameOver" where I needed to call "BETA_GameOver"

I hope someone else who has this problem can figure out a similar fix, it's probably (when working in singleplayer) just an incorrect level name.